# What time to close socket connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets

**Client**

```
Socket socket = new Socket("ip", 5555);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.println("Hello Server!");
out.close();
socket.close();
```

**Server**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);

while (true) {

    //keep listening
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    String line = in.readLine();

    System.out.println(line);

    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

if ignore concurrency issue, is the way to close sockets connection correct?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use *try-catch-finally* here?. Are you certain that you *don't* get any exceptions when using sockets?. I suggest closing resources in *finally* block.

Comment: Actually I use try-catch here, but I want to know is there a stander workflow to close the socket connection? I mean both client and server side have to invoke 'socket.close()' right? if client closed socket immediately after sent data, will it cause some exception like 'socket is close' while server tries to read data from stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if ignore concurrency issue, is the way to close sockets connection correct?

Yes, but you don't need to close the socket if you've already closed the output stream.

> if client closed socket immediately after sent data, will it cause some exception like 'socket is close' while server tries to read data from stream?

No. 'Socket is closed' means *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it. As long has the client has read everything the server is going to send, the client can close the socket: the server will read all the data the client has sent, and then get end-of-stream on the next read.

Comment: "the server will read all the data the client has sent, and then get end-of-stream on the next read" -- Are you sure about that? IIRC, when the client closes the socket there may still be unread data buffered at either client or server side which will be lost. This can be mitigated by having the client [linger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29) for some time upon `close()`.

Comment: @EJP Could the server possibly receive a SocketException while processing the data if it takes too much time? Will it be able to read the InputStream while there's data even if the socket has been closed?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it will be able to read the InputStream anyway https://hastebin.com/ahuxogidoc.cs

Comment: @JiimmyB No. If a host closes the socket while there is still pending outbound data, that data is not lost: it is all received by the peer followed by end of stream. If it closes the socket while there is pending *inbound* data, or the peer sends data after this end closes, the connection is reset and the data is lost.

Comment: @Writer See previous.

Comment: @JimmyB And `linger()` has nothing to do with it. All it does is block `close()` for up to the specified period while there is outgoing pending data. It doesn't affect the actual transmission of that data in any way. Unless you use it to reset the connection, which you simply shouldn't.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne No. If the socket is *not* set to linger, then, upon `close()`ing, the connection is closed immediately, which amounts to a connection reset, any pending data may be lost, and the other side may receive an exception accordingly. So in many cases it is actually essential to use lingering, specifically when you have no other way (application layer protocol,...) to ensure all data has actually been sent before closing the connection.